# Posterior Distribution Example.

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

Two questions, forgive me if they're stupid.

1. I thought the likelihood is a product of conditional pdfs. so why is the likelihood a simple binomial probability of n=10, x=3?
2. I've tried working it out but I don't understand how the numerator being a beta distribution simplifies to the last step? does the denominator equal 1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood here as well is a product of PDFs. You should note that the product of PDFs of a Bernoulli distribution gives the PDF of a Binomial distribution. More precisely, here we have,
$$
p(q|\mathbf x) = L(q;\mathbf x) = \prod_{i=1}^{10} q^{x_i}(1-q)^{1-x_i} = \binom{10}{3}q^3(1-q)^7
$$
To answer you second question, you should bear in mind that usually you do not need to compute the normalizing constants in the PDF of the posterior. It can be ignored! The reason is as follows:

Let $p(q|\mathbf x) = cq^{a-1}(1-q)^{b-1}$ for some constant $c$. Since we know that $p(q|\mathbf x)$ is indeed a PDF function and up to the constant $c$ it looks like the PDF of a Beta distribution, therefore $c$ should be exactly equal to $\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}$ which is the normalizing factor of the Beta distribution.

Now in your case the integral in the denominator is a constant and it can be ignored as well.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer!